# Add to PATH based on a Jenkins build parameter

Tags: windows, jenkins

I have a Jenkins (Windows / C++) project that is failing because some DLL's are not found on the `PATH`.  I know I can use the `EnvInject` plugin to update the `PATH`, but all the examples I found suggest to use a hard-coded folder. I want to add a folder that is specified as a build parameter.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

You could add to PATH in withEnv:

```
node {
  withEnv(["PATH+LIBS=${params.newPath}"]) {
    sh 'echo $PATH'
  }
}
```

The will prepend the specified path to the $PATH variable in external scripts (i.e. sh).

Comment: This does not answer the question of how to use a build parameter

Comment: Is this Groovy?

Comment: Can you explain "PATH+LIBS"?

Comment: Yes, it is groovy. withEnv() is a method call. We are passing the list [] with a single item. That item is a string "PATH+LIBS=${params.newPath}".  But since we double quoted the string, the ${} pattern interpolates the value of the variable into the string.

Comment: PATH+LIBS is just a feature of the withEnv method. If you have a pre-existing environment variable $PATH, you would clobber it with your entry if you just used PATH. So the wise thinkers who built withEnv allow for the syntax of [ORIG_VAR]+[SOME_DESCRIPTIVE_TEXT]=something_else. Then they know you don't want to clobber ORIG_VAR and instead, they prepend "something_else" to ORIG_VAR. https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-withenv-code-set-environment-variables

Comment: Did this answer your question about the using the param to add to PATH?

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is, define your path to add to the `PATH` variable, as a string build parameter, and then, as a build step (likely the first step in your case), execute the following batch command:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;%MY_BUILD_PARAM%
echo %PATH%
```

*The echo command is just to confirm it works*

Comment: I don't think that will affect subsequent build steps